# How can i make a string case insensitive in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example i am given this string as an input:
"HeLlo"
How can i make this case insensitive for later uses?
I want it to be equal to "hello" or "HELLo" etc...

Answer (score 1):

You have the `"your string".upper()` or `"your string".lower()` functions, which will allow you to compare the strings, assuring the comparison is case insensitive.